# how to add an image to the footer?

Tags: functions, images, footer

so I am looking through some code that I did not write. It has this piece of code here:

```
<nav id="footer-nav" class="span8 last">
  <a href="#"><button class="footerButton">Menu</button></a>
    <!--div class="menu-button">Menu</div-->
     <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Footer Menu') ); ?>
</nav><!-- id="footer-nav" -->
```

What I am interpreting from this piece of code is that there is a footer menu somewhere in the wp-dashboard, however, I do not see one.

I have also gone to the functions.php to locate:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'footer')); ?>
```

and no such code in functions.php. So is it safe to assume that there is no footer menu and this code is just sitting there doing nothing?

In the long-term I am trying to get a better understanding of the footer.php file because I need to add a png image next to this image:

```
<div class="span2 bbb last">
             <a title="John Eaton Homes, Inc. BBB Business Review" href="http://www.bbb.org/indianapolis/business-reviews/home-builders/john-eaton-homes-inc-in-indianapolis-in-40000093/#bbbonlineclick"><img alt="John Eaton Homes, Inc. BBB Business Review" style="border: 0;" src="http://seal-indy.bbb.org/seals/black-seal-120-70-john-eaton-homes-inc-40000093.png" /></a>
```

Here is the full footer.php:

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ): ?>
        <div class="main-wrapper clearfix footer-more">
                <img class="divider" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/divider.png" alt="" />
                <h1>Discover more from John Eaton Homes...</h1>
                <?php include dirname(__FILE__) . "/featured-links.php"; ?>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div> <!--main wrapper-->
        <footer id="main-footer">

        <div class="main-wrapper clearfix">


        <div class="span3">
                <a href="/"><img class="footer-logo" src="<?php the_field('logo','options'); ?>" alt="John Eaton Homes" /></a>
        </div>

                        <nav id="footer-nav" class="span8 last">
                                <a href="#"><button class="footerButton">Menu</button></a>
                                <!--div class="menu-button">Menu</div-->
                                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Footer Menu') ); ?>
                         </nav><!-- id="footer-nav" -->

             <div class="span2 bbb last">
             <a title="John Eaton Homes, Inc. BBB Business Review" href="http://www.bbb.org/indianapolis/business-reviews/home-builders/john-eaton-homes-inc-in-indianapolis-in-40000093/#bbbonlineclick"><img alt="John Eaton Homes, Inc. BBB Business Review" style="border: 0;" src="http://seal-indy.bbb.org/seals/black-seal-120-70-john-eaton-homes-inc-40000093.png" /></a>
             </div>

         </div>
        </footer><!-- id="main-footer" -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried just adding this:

```
<img src=“images/bagi-logo.png"/>
```

but it does not appear next to the image class of span2 bbb last where it is being requested. It does appear below footer-logo image when I place it next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like several different pointers may be useful:

- Are you working on a theme that was custom developed for your website? If not, you should create a child theme so that anytime the parent theme receives an update, your changes won't be overwritten.
- The image you're trying to add should either be uploaded through WordPress's media library, or saved in the theme files. Your source `"images/bagi-logo.png"` is looking in `"http://yoursite.com/images/bagi-logo.png"` for the file. If you are including it as part of the theme, it should instead be located somewhere like this: `"http://yoursite.com/wp-content/themes/yourthemename/images/bagi-logo.png"`.
- Menus called by `wp_nav_menu` can be accessed in a couple of different ways. One is to log into wp-admin and go to Appearance > Menus. From there, you can see whether or not that particular menu has been created. If any HTML output is occurring, then you do have a menu saved in WP somewhere. This type of data is saved in the database rather than in theme files.
- From the sound of the classes, `"span3"` is probably floated, meaning that if you place anything outside that div it will push below the area you want it in. You'd do well to inspect the CSS for troubleshooting that part. You may need to either place the image inside the `"span3"` div or adjust all the span numbers and add a final div with a span number to wrap around the image.

Comment: WebElaine, you are all that an a bag of chips (too lame?). Thank you. As I was waiting for the answer, I was able to load the image inside the "span2 bbb last" div class. Thank you for the pointers too. Seriously, you know your stuff, you have improved me.